# Torch: How to apply the torch built-in optimizers to tandem models?

Tags: optimization, lua, neural-network, torch

Recently, I start learning torch. But, the following question really stumps me. A seq2seq demo is available [here](https://github.com/Element-Research/rnn/blob/master/examples/encoder-decoder-coupling.lua), and the definition of model is showed as follow:

```
local enc = nn.Sequential()
enc:add(nn.LookupTableMaskZero(opt.vocab_size, opt.hidden_size))
enc.lstmLayers = {}
for i=1,opt.layer_nums do
    if opt.use_seqlstm then
        enc.lstmLayers[i] = nn.SeqLSTM(opt.hidden_size, opt.hidden_size)
        enc.lstmLayers[i]:maskZero()
        enc:add(enc.lstmLayers[i])
    else
        enc.lstmLayers[i] = nn.LSTM(opt.hidden_size, opt.hidden_size):maskZero(1)
        enc:add(nn.Sequencer(enc.lstmLayers[i]))
    end
end
enc:add(nn.Select(1, -1))

-- Decoder
local dec = nn.Sequential()
dec:add(nn.LookupTableMaskZero(opt.vocab_size, opt.hidden_size))
dec.lstmLayers = {}
for i=1,opt.layer_nums do
    if opt.use_seqlstm then
        dec.lstmLayers[i] = nn.SeqLSTM(opt.hidden_size, opt.hidden_size)
        dec.lstmLayers[i]:maskZero()
        dec:add(dec.lstmLayers[i])
    else
        dec.lstmLayers[i] = nn.LSTM(opt.hidden_size, opt.hidden_size):maskZero(1)
        dec:add(nn.Sequencer(dec.lstmLayers[i]))
    end
end
dec:add(nn.Sequencer(nn.MaskZero(nn.Linear(opt.hidden_size, opt.vocab_size), 1)))
dec:add(nn.Sequencer(nn.MaskZero(nn.LogSoftMax(), 1)))
local criterion = nn.SequencerCriterion(nn.MaskZeroCriterion(nn.ClassNLLCriterion(),1))
```

In the original version, the parameters of this model is updated in the following way:

```
enc:zeroGradParameters()
dec:zeroGradParameters()

-- Forward pass
local encOut = enc:forward(encInSeq)
forwardConnect(enc, dec)
local decOut = dec:forward(decInSeq)
--print(decOut)
local err = criterion:forward(decOut, decOutSeq)

print(string.format("Iteration %d ; NLL err = %f ", i, err))

-- Backward pass
local gradOutput = criterion:backward(decOut, decOutSeq)
dec:backward(decInSeq, gradOutput)
backwardConnect(enc, dec)
local zeroTensor = torch.Tensor(encOut):zero()
enc:backward(encInSeq, zeroTensor)

dec:updateParameters(opt.learningRate)
enc:updateParameters(opt.learningRate)
```

However, I really wonder whether I can use the built-in optimizers in *optim* to train the model above. So, I tried the following method:

```
-- Concatenate the enc's and dec's parameters
local x = torch.cat(e_x, d_x)
local dl_dx = torch.cat(e_dl_dx, d_dl_dx)

local feval = function(x_new)
    if x ~= x_new then
        x:copy(x_new)
        local e_x_new = torch.Tensor(x_new{{1, 1322000}})
        local d_x_new = torch.Tensor(x_new{{1322001, 2684100}})
        e_x:copy(e_x_new)
        d_x:copy(d_x_new)
    end

    dl_dx:zero()
    e_dl_dx = dl_dx{{1, 1322000}}
    d_dl_dx = dl_dx{{1322001, 2684100}}

    -- Forward pass
    local encOut = enc:forward(encInSeq)
    forwardConnect(enc, dec)
    local decOut = dec:forward(decInSeq)

    local err = criterion:forward(decOut, decOutSeq)

    -- print(string.format("Iteration %d ; NLL err = %f ", i, err))

    -- Backward pass
    local gradOutput = criterion:backward(decOut, decOutSeq)
    dec:backward(decInSeq, gradOutput)
    backwardConnect(enc, dec)
    local zeroTensor = torch.Tensor(encOut):zero()
    enc:backward(encInSeq, zeroTensor)

    x = torch.cat(e_x, d_x)
    dl_dx = torch.cat(e_dl_dx, d_dl_dx)
    return err, dl_dx
end

_, fs = optim.adadelta(feval, x, optim_configs)
```

But, it didn't work and I got an error:

```
encoder-decoder-coupling.lua:161: torch.DoubleTensor has no call operator
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'dl_dx'
    encoder-decoder-coupling.lua:161: in function 'opfunc'
    /home/mydesktop/torch/install/share/lua/5.2/optim/adadelta.lua:31: in function 'adadelta'
    encoder-decoder-coupling.lua:185: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...ktop/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:145: in main chunk
    [C]: in ?
```

All in all, how to apply the built-in optimizers in *optim* to update the parameters in more than one models? Do I have to overwrite the *adadelta.lua*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say exactly what the error is without having access to your complete script. In any case, I have suggestions regarding the above:

1. avoid creating tensors in feval (or any other inner loop). Use buffers that you can resize and reuse to avoid memory allocations.
2. don't use torch.cat to concatenate parameters. It allocates memory every time it is called. Instead use `nn.Container():add(enc):add(dec):getParameters()` instead of `torch.cat(enc:getParameters(), dec:getParameters())`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works! Thank you very very much!!! `nn.Container():add(enc):add(dec)` makes the parameters in both models can be updated in the optimizer `optim.adadelta()`. Thank you again!